# How to upload large file to azure using typescript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, azure-data-lake, azure-sdk

I was looking for a way to upload large big files to azure data lake store using typescript but end up with no answer, have any one done this? Thanks in advance.

------------EDITED----------------
I found a way to give REST API calls to send data to azure data lake, this is the link i'm following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-rest-api.

It is successful through PostMan, but now the big hurdle i am facing is the way to make these requests in typescript. Have anyone did this?

Comment: I'm trying to give REST API calls

Comment: I'm trying since a while giving REST calls through typescript, this is what i want to do https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-rest-api, only hurdle i am facing is the way to use for making such requests.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of samples for Typescript. However, if you are trying to upload large files using the REST API, you will need to handle errors, retries, etc in your code. Instead of the REST API, can you use the SDKs that we provide?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-java-sdk - This is link to Java SDK. We also have Python SDK and .NET SDK. These SDKs handle a lot of the heavylifting for you that needs to be done when using the REST APIs.

Thanks,
Sachin Sheth
Program Manager, Azure Data Lake.

Comment: thanks, you are right SDKs are more efficient but since my language is bound to be Typescript only, what possibilities i have in that?